# Function works in immediate window but not in worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a public function which looks up a user supplied number in a different workbook and extract information from it. The user will give a plan number (which is really a string with a number in it) and the function will look up this number in another workbook to collect a file number and a crossing associated with the plan number.Right now I have this function working when it is called in the immediate window but it will return #VALUE! when called on in a worksheet. Here is what i have.

```
Public Function indexfind(Plan As String) As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim d As Range
    Dim filenumber As String
    Dim crossing As String
    Dim Plannumber As Double
    Plannumber = Val(Left(Plan, 4))

    Workbooks.Open ("File Path")
    Workbooks("PLANINDE.xls").Worksheets("Index").Activate
    Set wks = Workbooks("PLANINDE.xls").Worksheets("Index")
    Set d = wks.Range("G:G").Find(Plannumber, , xlValues)

    If d Is Nothing Then
        indexfind = "Plan Does Not Exist"
        Workbooks("PLANINDE.xls").Close (False)
    Exit Function
    End If

    filenumber = wks.Cells(d.Row, 2).Value
    crossing = wks.Cells(d.Row, 3).Value

    Workbooks("PLANINDE.xls").Close (False)

    Debug.Print filenumber
    Debug.Print crossing
    Debug.Print Plannumber

    indexfind = "No Plan Folder. File Number:" & filenumber & " crossing:" & crossing
End Function
```

Comment: There's no `Debug.Print` how is this showing in immediate window? If you're removed it, please put it back in so we know where you're debugging

Comment: I am calling the function in the immediate window
?indexfind(plan)

Comment: Try putting `Debug.Print Plannumber` after that variable is set, maybe you're getting improper extraction of your number?

Comment: I just tried debugging all variables. They are returning the corerct values.

Comment: Put a break point on Workbooks.Open, then use function is worksheet and  step thru to see how far you can get to. Will advice to Open workbook with ReadOnly option. You will use this function just once in the workbook right?

Comment: Though i do notice there is a space in front of the plannumber maybe this has something to do with it? This is odd because using Val should only return numbers and no spaces..

Comment: I'd suggest an `On Error GoTo` segment and try outputting the error message with `Str(Err.Number)` & `Err.Description`.

Comment: Is `indexfind` decelared in a standard module?

Comment: yes it is a standard module

Comment: You probably don't need to `Workbooks("PLANINDE.xls").Worksheets("Index").Activate`, which might be triggering other code. Calculation might be kicking in too, when you open workbooks.

Comment: Maldred- I do not get any errors from the debugger when I call it in the immediate window. Im not sure what you are asking, can you please clarify.

Comment: You should also try to avoid using `Val` as it is not  locale aware - you'd be better off using `CDbl`

Comment: Put `On Error Goto ErrHandler` before `Workbooks.Open ("File Path")` and then create an error message at then end; something like... `ErrHandler: Debug.print "Error Code: " & Str(Err.Number) & Chr(13) & "Description: " & Err.Description`. If this doesn't output any error messages then it seems there are some hidden characters some where and it might be best to parse the input manually rather than using `VAL()`

Comment: ThuderFrame- I changed Val to using CDbl(Plan). It is doign the same thing, it is able to extract the plannumber properly but still has a space infront for some reason.

Comment: The structure of your function is not good for what you want, for example, you have used `workbook activate` which does not make sense if you want to simply open a workbook (rather visible or in background), extract the data you need, close it and show it where it was called

Comment: Maldred- i did what you suggested. here is what i get: Error Code:  0
Description:

Comment: Ibo- I've commented out the Activate part. it is still causing the same problem

Comment: I don't think `Plannumber` should be a `Double`. It is not a good idea to match `Double` types due to precision issues.

Comment: Maldred- When i call the function in a work sheet i do get an error
Error Code:  9
Description: Subscript out of range

However when i call it in the immediate window it does not give an error and it returns the proper values.

Comment: ja27- should I change it to integer instead? what do you suggest?

Comment: you have used `If d Is Nothing Then`, that is a wrong line, `is nothing` should be used only for objects. The Excel FIND function returns the position (as a number) of one text string inside another, if not found it returns #VALUE. So you should use isnumeric/isnumber function or iserror function

Comment: ignore my last comment, now I can see that you have used FIND worksheet function to find the value of the cell. It is still the same mistake, you should not use `is nothing` to compare

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. I have to leave for now and will continue with this tomorrow.

Comment: Ibo- what do you suggest I use instead of Is Nothing? What I am trying to do there is create an if statement where If (d is blank) then Do this. How else can i achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code cannot work as a function called directly from a worksheet.  VBA UDF's are restricted as to what they can do.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: So there is no way to do this on excel? I have a list of plan numbers and I need to fill a column with information from another sheet. Do you know any way I can quickly achieve this rather than doing it manually?

Comment: You can use a Sub instead of a function, and run it from a button on the worksheet.  Then you're not opening and closing the file for every value to be looked up.